# Passing arrays to qsub script

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, qsub

How do I pass arrays as a variable list via qsub job script in PBS environment?

For example:

```
arr1=(1 2 3); arr2(a b c); qsub -v array1=("${arr1[@]}"), array2=("$arr2[@]") job_script.bash
```

where `job_script.bash` has array variables `array1` and `array2`.

When I try to run the above command to submit my job I get following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Am I missing something in my syntax?

I looked any many forums for help but not finding anything regarding passing arrays as above.

Can anyone help me with above situation?

Comment: Explain qsub and PBS.

Comment: qsub is the command to submit job in clusters with grid computing environment:
http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-1-4/Content/topics/commands/qsub.htm
PBS is the grid computing software that provides the platform for the jobs to be submitted to computing clusters and executed:
http://www.pbsworks.com/Product.aspx?id=26

Comment: Here is Wikipedia link to explain PBS in layman terms:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Batch_System

Comment: Look closely: what is wrong with `array2=("$arr2[@]")` -- something is missing...

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not appear to be with `qsub`, rather you did not create your `arr2` variable correctly in the shell...

```
#  You did this...
arr1=(1 2 3); arr2(a b c); 

#  You meant this...
arr1=(1 2 3); arr2=(a b c);
```

Answer (score -1):

I use qsub on a daily basis. maybe a dumb answer, but could the problem be due to the space you leave between your two array variables in the -v argument?

i.e. your qsub command should be 
"qsub -v array1=("${arr1[@]}"),array2=("$arr2[@]") job_script.bash"

Comment: sorry, this doesn't work either. So I also need an answer to this question

Comment: the only thing I've found that works is to submit your array as a (string) variable in the form of a string-separated list, then add a line to your pbs script which separates the list into an array

for for example if array1 is a list of 3 files, create a variable called `array1list="file1:file2:file3"`. Then in your pbs script add a line like `array1=($(echo $array1list|sed 's/:/ /g'))` and you can then use it as an array in the rest of your code